# Using sub folders in the Source folder for Visual Studios 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directory

I am currently creating a small project over the summer using c++ and visual studio 2010. I wanted to organize the individual `.cpp` and `.h` files into their own folders in the project directory. While I use filters in the actual project, I do understand that these are filters, not folders.

So my question is this. In my source, I currently have a header folder called `GameStateManger.h`, and a folder called `Tank_Headers` and `Tank_CPPs`. I also have `Tank.h`, and `Tank.cpp`, in their respective folders. My problem is that in GameStateManager, I have this `#include "Tank_Headers\Tank.h"`, however, in my `Tank.h`, when I type `#include...` nothing shows up. I cannot find anything. However, if I make a new header, and put it in just source, I can search for those folders. I want to be able to organize my `.h` files and my `.cpp` files into individual folders in my source folder, so it is much more organized, considering the project might get very big very soon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `#include "Tank.h"`

That should work as long as you add the file to your project first. Drag it from explorer into whatever filter you want it organized it into.

Sorry I forgot to add:

You need to add the subfolder to your project.  Go to the project properties, look under C/C++ and add it to Additional Include Folders.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I probably should I have mentioned, I did make sure when I created the file, I made it in the correct spot. I also tried removing it and adding it back in. It simply cannot find the folder. Perhaps it is Properties problem?
However, I did try your method, and it returned this error, 
'Source\Tank_CPPs\Tank.cpp(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Tank.h': No such file or directory'

Comment: @user3597359  See my addition above.  I added the additional information you need.